# ArcMap 10.1 Intersect Not Adding Points at All Intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, intersect

I have run the Intersect tool on a streets centerline layer.  I tried it on a dissolved version of the lines and also a split version of the lines.  The tool is not giving me a point at each intersection in either case.  I have included an image below.  The red circles are an example of the areas that should also have points.

[image]

Comment: What does one of these "should be intersections" look like close up?

Comment: Here is a 1:1 view of one of the intersections. I thought initially it was a connectivity issue but it doesn't appear that it is that by looking at them closely.  http://i.imgur.com/UJYXsdl.png

Comment: Significant part of your intersection points look like endpoints to me. I'd say run multipart to single part and try again.